# is it possible to keep the format of my page in portrait mode (mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been designing a tribute as part of the freecodecamp projects.

The layout on my laptop is here https://codepen.io/9788cl/pen/WExxEK

added snippet below aswell. (just ran the snippet and the formating is off in that aswell.

I am trying to achieve  centered title at top, image & quote/bio below that side by side,  font awesome icons below the image.

when i viewed the page on my phone the layout was correct when in landscape,  but when moving to portrait the quote & text moves under the image,  & the social media icons below them looking quite messy.  Is there anything i can do about this?

```css
body{ margin:20px;}

.main-title2
{
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size:72px;
  border-color:#000000;
  border-width:4px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-radius:10px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000000;
  padding-bottom:15px;
  }

.paragraph-font
{
 font-family: 'Electrolize', sans-serif;

  font-size: 18px;
}

.img-rounded 
{
   border-width:4px;
   border-radius:10px;  
   width:500px;
   height:400px;
}

#bio
{
  width:600px;
  border-width:2px;
 border-radius:10px;
  margin-left:50px;
  
  }

#quote
{
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size:24px;
  border-width:2px;
 border-radius:10px;
  margin-top:25px;
  }
h3
{
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size:24px;
  border-width:2px;
 border-radius:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  
}

#twitter
{
  
  padding-right:140px;
  padding-left:140px;
}
.fa-instagram
{
  color:#000000
}
.fa-twitter
{
  color:#000000
}
.fa-facebook
{
  color:#000000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

               <head>
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script" rel="stylesheet">
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
                 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Revalia" rel="stylesheet">
                 
                 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Electrolize" rel="stylesheet">
                 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">
                 
                 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script" rel="stylesheet">

</head>


<div class="container-fluid">
  
  <h1 class="main-title2 text-center">Elon Musk Tribute Page</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VdjsurFddLQ/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="elon-musk" </img>
    </div>
    <div id="bio">
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <blockquote id ="quote" class="text-center">
        " I think that's the single best piece of advice: constantly think about how you could be doing things better and questioning yourself. "</blockquote>
      <h3 class="text-center" ><strong>-Elon Musk</strong></h3>
      <p class="text-center paragraph-font">Born in South Africa in 1971, Elon Musk became a multimillionaire in his late 20s when he sold his start-up company, Zip2, to a division of Compaq Computers. He achieved more success by founding X.com in 1999, SpaceX in 2002 and Tesla Motors in 2003. Musk made headlines in May 2012, when SpaceX launched a rocket that would send the first commercial vehicle to the International Space Station. He bolstered his portfolio with the purchase of SolarCity in 2016, and cemented his standing as a leader of industry by taking on an advisory role in the early days of President Donald Trump's administration</p>
      </div> <!--col-xs-7 -->
        
   </div> <!--id="bio" -->
  </div> <!-- row-->
  
  
<div id="social-media">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/elonmusk/?hl=en"><i id="instagram"class="fa fa-instagram fa-5x"></i></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/elonmusk"> <i id="twitter"class="fa fa-twitter fa-5x"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Elon-Musk-19958149870/"><i id="facebook"class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x"></i></a>
  </div>
  
   
  
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using some framework to responsive layout?

Answer (score 1):

Read about using media queries for responsive design: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries